# FLUTTER: add border to font

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I have seen a font called poppins extra bold:

[image]

I added it to my project but I don't know how to add black border.

Answer (score 0):

please check below answer :

```
Widget textWithStroke({String text, String fontFamily, double fontSize: 12, double strokeWidth: 1, Color textColor: Colors.white, Color strokeColor: Colors.black}) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                fontFamily: fontFamily,
                foreground: Paint()
                  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                  ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
                  ..color = strokeColor,
              ),
            ),
            Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: fontFamily, fontSize: fontSize, color: textColor)),
          ],
        );
      }
```

Comment: 1. it's link only answer ...2. it's link to another question here on SO ....3. you have enough reputation to mark question as duplicate

Comment: ... and now after edit, it is a copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146269/how-to-decorate-text-stroke-in-flutter#answer-59759359) ... posting someone else answer as your is basically stealing