# How to draw only stroke of a text in flutter canvas?

Tags: flutter, text, fonts, flutter-canvas

I am trying to implement a feature in my flutter app where user can toggle between stroke and fill view, for text (like adobe illustrator or similar). How to get this effect in flutter canvas.

[image: image of stroke only text]

Here is a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919076/outline-effect-to-text) asking how to achieve this in CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it by using the `foreground` property in the `TextStyle`.

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Outlined Text',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        foreground: Paint()
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeWidth = 3
          ..color = Colors.black, // <-- Border color
      ),
    ),
    const Text(
      'Outlined Text',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: Colors.white, // <-- Inner color
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Reference

[How to decorate text stroke in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146269/how-to-decorate-text-stroke-in-flutter)