# Flutter: Add A stroke to a Text Widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add astroke to my text in Flutter.

I'm aware this has been probably asked dozens of times, but I've tried every solution I could find and all of them are outdated.

What I've tried:

[Using Paint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146269/how-to-decorate-text-stroke-in-flutter)

**The accepted solution's code:**

```html
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          // Stroked text as border.
          const Text(
            'Greetings, planet!',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 40,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Greetings, planet!',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 40,
              foreground: Paint()
                ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                ..strokeWidth = 6
                ..color = Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          // Solid text as fill.
        ],
      ),
```

**The paint solution:**

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/outlined_text try to use this package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue for Impeller [#126010](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126010), you can find many issues like this. Basically the stroke for iOS in unimplemented. You can try running your code on an Android simulator and will notice that the accepted solution you posted works fine.

There is another workaround with shadows, the concept is to add 4 shadows to the text widget, one for each side, something like this:

```
const Text(
        'Greetings, planet!',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 40,
          shadows: [
            Shadow(
                // bottomLeft
                offset: Offset(-1.5, -1.5),
                color: Colors.blue),
            Shadow(
                // bottomRight
                offset: Offset(1.5, -1.5),
                color: Colors.blue),
            Shadow(
                // topRight
                offset: Offset(1.5, 1.5),
                color: Colors.blue),
            Shadow(
                // topLeft
                offset: Offset(-1.5, 1.5),
                color: Colors.blue),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

This "works", but the final result is not as good as it would be with `Paint()`.

Comment: Not as good as Paint() like you said, but it's the closest it can be. Thank you!